# Why is my fetch() not returning the whole row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP and I can't quite wrap my head around why fetch() isn't returning the whole row and why I can't reference the password from the query in my login.php file. This website is meant to be intentionally vulnerable so I can use it as target practice for my python tools. I found the issue when trying to compare the user inputted password and the password correlating to the username in the database. At the end of the day, I just want to be able to pull the correct password from the database and compare it to the password the user typed in the password field. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I was using this article as a guide: https://dzone.com/articles/ceate-a-login-system-using-html-php-and-mysql

Right now $row['password'] = "" when in the database it should equal "badpassword".

**config.php**

```
<?php
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost');
define('DBUSERNAME', 'root');
define('DBPASSWORD', 'toor');
define('DBNAME', 'userlogin');

$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);

if($db == false){
  die("Error: connection error." . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && $_SESSION["userid"] == true) {
  header("location: welcome.html");
  exit;
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);
  if(empty($username)) {
    echo "<h1>Please enter your username.</h1>";
  }
  if(empty($password)) {
    echo "<h1>Please enter your password.</h1>";
  }
  if(empty($error)) {
    if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?")){
      $query->bind_param('s', $username);
      $query->execute();
      $row = $query->fetch();
      if($row){
        if($password == $row['password']){
          $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
          $_SESSION["user"] = $row;
          header("location: welcome.html");
          exit;
        } else {
          echo "<h1>The password is not valid.</h1>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<h1>No user exists with that username.</h1>";
      }
    }
    $query->close();
  }
  mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="box" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    <br>
    <a href="register.html">Register</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: If you want to use `fetch()` then it seems that you must also use `bind_result()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php I don't use mysqli myself, so I'm not sure whether that is the issue or not. What is in `$row` when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: More to the point, it seems that you are storing passwords in plain text. Don't do this - use `password_hash()` to store them, and `password_verify()` to compare them. You will need to expand the column that you store the password in, too, as the hashed password is much longer than 25 characters. That article you refer to uses these functions, but you seem to have missed that bit out.

Comment: @droopsnoot Not using hashed passwords was intentional. I'm making a purposefully vulnerable website that I can use as target practice for my python tools.

Comment: Please use `CHARSET=utf8mb4` in any modern project

Comment: @droopsnoot hmmmm var_dump($row) == bool(true)

Comment: @NickLueth did you try using `bind_result()` as noted earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use $query->get_result() and fetch_assoc() to fetch row :

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
if ($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?") ) {
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $query->execute();
    $res = $query->get_result();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    print_r( $row );
}
$query->close();
```

login.php may look like this :

- note 1. header changed to echo for display only, not redirect.
- note 2. $query->close(); and mysqli_close($db); added before exit.

```
$error = '';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(empty($username)) {
        echo "<h1>Please enter your username.</h1>";
    }

    if(empty($password)) {
        echo "<h1>Please enter your password.</h1>";
    }

    if(empty($error)) {
        if ($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?") ) {

            $query->bind_param('s', $username);
            $query->execute();
            $res = $query->get_result();
            $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
            
            if($row){
                if($password == $row['password']){
                  $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                  $_SESSION["user"] = $row;
                  echo("location: welcome.html");
                  $query->close();
                  mysqli_close($db);
                  exit;
                } else {
                  echo "<h1>The password is not valid.</h1>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<h1>No user exists with that username.</h1>";
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    } // empty($error)
    mysqli_close($db);
} // server
```